# How or why were most of the "different" Apache projects so called

Tags: java

Please ignore the obivous ones like

- commons
- log4j
- jakarta Which is of course the capital of "Java".

but rather think about ones like

- Tika

Answer (score 0):

There are no real rules. People call their projects as they want to: the words they like, the words that have meaning, or have no meaning (like Acegi, which is obviously AbCdEfGhI).